# TF30170 : Can't create new Team Projects anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

We used to have a great time with our TFS 2010 installation, but all of a sudden it seems to stab us in the back.

When we try to create a new Team Project (either via VS2010 or VS2012 Team Explorer), TFS encounters an error when importing the Process Templates. It doesn't matter which of the installed Templates i select, the error is always the same.

```
2013-01-16T11:11:08 | Modul: Work Item Tracking | Thread: 39 | Uploading task type from file "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\TPW_tmp447E.tmp\WorkItem     Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Bug.xml" hochgeladen...
---Begin Exception---
Zeit: 2013-01-16T11:11:08
Modul: Engine
Exception Description: TF30162: Error at Task "WITs" from Group "WorkItemTracking".
Exception Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.PcwException
Exception Message: TF24016: Team project "MyInfoservice" not found.
Stacktrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.TaskExecutor.PerformTask(IProjectComponentCreator componentCreator, ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationEngine.RunTask(Object taskObj)
--   Inner Exception   --
Ausnahmemeldung: TF24016: Team project "MyInfoservice" not found. (Type WitPcwFatalException)

Ausnahmestapelüberwachung:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.ContextWrapper.get_Project()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.UploadTypeDefinition(String file, Boolean execute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.WitPcwTask.WorkItemTypesTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Parse(ContextWrapper wrapper, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean fExecute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WitPcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Execute(ProjectCreationContext ctxt, XmlNode taskXml)

---End Exception---
```

**EDIT :** My colleague just found out that this doesn't occur on any other machines, so it must be our Visual Studio instances that are messed up.

So why are they messed up? We caused a desaster by making attempts at desaster recovery (What happens if we have just the database dump of our TFS Collection?). What we've done, in short:

- Make a backup of TFS Database (without detaching it from the TFS)
- Create a second Server and reattach the database there
- Run TfsConfig Recover on the DataBase

At first sight, the result seemed to be OK, but at a closer look, many problems surfaced. I guess they go back to the fact that visual studio connected to two servers with the same project- and collection GUIDs, but that's just a guess. Now we're trying to get our machines back to work the way they did when only one TFS was being connected to.

Tried but not working:

- devenv resetsettings
- deleting all VisualStudio and TeamFoundation folders below `C:\users\user1\AppData\Local` and `Roaming`
- deleting registry keys that contain the TFS server names

Can anyone point me in the right direction what else we can try?

Comment: Did you try the steps described on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/50a77a15-84aa-4bf5-9070-9b943c498baf ?

Comment: @SvenS If you refer to stamping the WorkItem Cache : Yes, but no effect. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few more or less desperate attempts I was finally able to solve this.

Since the exception occured when a file from my local Temp folder was uploaded to TFS, I tried  clearing the entire TEMP folder. That did the trick. The relevant information is the first line of the log output I posted above.

```
Uploading task type from file "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\TPW_tmp447E.tmp\WorkItemTracking\TypeDefinitions\Bug.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after restoring a TFS 2012 Express collection from backup.  I resolved it by deleting the TFS cache on the local dev. machine.  I just removed the entire **Cache** folder...

```
C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
```

If you have another dev. machine handy then you can check if you can create a TFS project on it.  If you can then the problem is with your dev. machine, most likely the cache.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I créate a Project it says the Project exists and if I try to delete with "tfsdeleteproject" it says the Project don't exists.